# Inheriting a template class in C++ with unsupported type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a template `Base` class which I want to inherit. The `Base` class has a public method which makes an assumption about the template type. A simplified version of the code is presented below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename V>
class Base {
 public:
  virtual void print() {
    a = "a";
    cout << "Base class" ;
  }
  void callIt() {
    print();
  }
  V a;
};

class Derived : public Base<int> {
 public:
  void print() override {
    cout << "Derived class\n";
  }
};


int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.callIt();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with GCC 6.2.0 gives me this error:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void Base<V>::print() [with V = int]':
test.cpp:13:10:   required from 'void Base<V>::callIt() [with V = int]'
test.cpp:28:12:   required from here
test.cpp:9:7: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
     a = "a";
     ~~^~~~~
```

I want to completely hide the `Base` class implementation of the `print()` method from the compiler. How can I do that?

**EDIT:** Ironically, commenting out the line `a = "a";` allows the code to compile successfully and will print out `Derived class`.

Comment: Sorry, why does `Base::print` make an assumption about `V` if `Base` is meant to be inherited by a more general template?

Comment: @Brian `Base` is a part of a library that I have no control over it but I want other functionalities that it provides.

Comment: Do you know what's really fun? Comment out `a = "a";` and see the output. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Kci1HFRYtKbtbLk8

(Spoiler alert: the output is `Derived class`. What??)

Comment: @JackDeeth Yes, that's what has confused me.

Comment: I don't think hiding `Base::print` is what you want since then it won't be callable using the base class. I think what you should be looking for is making it pure virtual when it is not supported.

Comment: Can you modify Base at all?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get your code working if you add a specialization for `Base<int>::print()` before declaring `Derived`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename V>
class Base {
 public:
  virtual void print() {
    a = "a";
    cout << "Base class" ;
  }
  void callIt() {
    print();
  }
  V a;
};

template <>
void Base<int>::print() {
    cout << "Specialization\n";
}

class Derived : public Base<int> {
 public:
  void print() override {
    cout << "Derived class\n";
  }
};


int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.callIt();
  return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85fd2daf72d9876e)

Be careful doing this though: it breaks the assumptions the author of `Base` made about what types work with the template, and could easily lead to hard-to-trace bugs in library code.

Comment: Why is `Base::callIt()` needed? @Javad cannot add it to `Base`, and calling `d.print()` works fine: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7bFxmV88g1izYBbc

Comment: Because it's in OP's code.  `Base::callIt()` is the reason OP can't drop the `virtual` qualifier from `Base::print()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that. But to be fair, it was edited into the original post after I'd copied the code into Wandbox :)

Comment: Sorry, the initial version was oversimplified.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `print` is virtual, it has to be instantiated whenever you inherit from `Base` (because compiler needs to generate proper vtable) - even when the function is not called yet. It would not be the case if `print` was a non-virtual member - in this case it would be instantiated only when called.

The only solution I can think of is to see if you can get rid of virtual functions here - and if you can't, sorry, you are out of luck.

Comment: You're right but I think I had oversimplified the code. I just updated the code. `print()` is being called by `Base::callIt()`. Dropping virtual in the old code would help but in the new code it doesn't. I tried to comment out `a = "a";` and compiled the code and got `Base class` instead of `Derived class`. Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying to isolate the problem:

```
template <typename V>
class Base {
 public:
  virtual void print() {
    a = "a";
  }

  V a;
};

int main()
{
  Base<int> b;
}
```

results in:

```
<source>:5:7: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
a = "a";
```

This is because we are in effect saying:

```
int a = "a";
```

and of course that's an error because you can't assign a `const char*` to an `int`.

So the only reasonable conclusion to draw here is that `Base<T>` has been designed with the constraint that there must exist an accessible conversion from `const char*` to `T`.

If you want `T` to be anything else, then this base class is not suitable and you'll need to find another way to achieve what you want (encapsulation?).